# chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced not firing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on Google extension code and am trying to listen to the `chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced` event, but the `onTabReplaced` event is never getting fired.

I am using Chrome version 30.0.1587.2 Canary (Windows 7).

Here is how my manifest file looks. Any help will be appreciated.

**manifest.json:**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "abcdef",
  "description": "abcdef",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": [
         "tabs",
         "webNavigation",
         "background",
         "storage",
         "<all_urls>"
   ],
   "background": {
       "scripts": ["bg.js"]
   }
}
```

**bg.js:**

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onTabReplaced.addListener(function (details) {
    // This event is not working in chrome.
    console.log('webNavigation.onTabReplaced-- old tab id: ' +details.replacedTabId +' new Tab Id ' + details.tabId);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`onTabReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onTabReplaced) event is *only* fired when a [prerendered](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender) tab is replaced. If you want to detect when a new document has loaded, use the [`chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCommitted) event.

Comment: In my extension, i want to retrieve old tab Id which just replaced by new Tab Id if user types new URL in same Tab. That way i can keep my TabUrlsAssociation[tabId] = URL collection up to date.  If webNavigation.onTabReplaced is not correct event than which event should give me both tab Id ? Similar event chrome.tabs.onReplaced also seems to not working.

Comment: The `tabId` does not change if the user navigates to a different page.

Comment: I am seeing different Tab id if Url changes. More details related to issue explained here.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226180

Comment: @apdev The `onTabReplaced` event will not be fired if no pre-rendering occurs. Try to trigger pre-rendering using the method described in https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226180#c8